# Where is the eth2 code actually?

Tags: go-ethereum, eth-2.0

I am confused as where the eth2 code actually is.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases is at v1.12.0, which is weird if it already reflects the actual eth2 code - I would have switched to 2.x after the merge or even at phase 0 of eth2.

Is it a fork/different repo altogether?

Comment: There was never a 2.0 version. All the changes required by the merge were made in a 1.xx branch.

Comment: Ah cool thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by eth2 code. To run a node, you must run a consensus and an execution client.
[image: consensus clients and execution clients diverisity]

They work in sync but are totally different and have their own code. So if you have the Prysm consensus client and the Geth execution client, the code you're looking for is [github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/](https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/) and [github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum), respectively.

This is probably why the execution client release's version does not reflect the change to eth2 as you suggested. Because the main change was the addition of the consensus client.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You can validate the answer if you found it helpful!